# Angular (7.2.10) app failing to load on Chrome on iOS 12.4.1

Tags: javascript, ios, angular

I'm currently working on an Angular application (7.2.10) and on the latest version of iOS available on my device (12.4.1) we have hit an issue that I can't seem to figure out. The issue only occurs on Chrome on iOS, I am unable to replicate this issue on any other browser on the affected devices. The iPad air (1st gen) I am running against is using Chrome version 77.0.3865.93. It was first reported by a colleague using an iPad Pro, and we have has a couple of clients call in saying it's not working on their iPhones.

If we load the entry point to our web application the screen is completely blank. Nothing loads, and the spinner stops immediately.

I've tried a few avenues to try and get to the root of the problem, but I am yet to get anywhere. I have...

1. Using [ios-webview-app](https://github.com/paulirish/iOS-WebView-App) to run iOS simulator within safari on a mac. This just resulted in the website loading as normal, so something wasn't being simulated correctly.
2. [ios-webkit-debug-proxy](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy) to attempt to get developer tools in chrome for iOS. This ended up not working at all, either I was unable to get it running or our particular network setup meant it would never work.
3. Using [weinre](https://people.apache.org/%7Epmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Home.html) to get some sort of developer tools to read network activity/logs. I wasn't able to get this running initially, however after a bit of tinkering I was able to use this alongside [Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/) to get developer tools. Unfortunately, nothing in the logs or DOM was erroring or showed any reason as to why it might not be starting correctly.

After connecting via number 3, I was able to find out that angular itself is not bootstrapping, and no javascript is being executed on the page (from within the transpiled code, javascript included in other .js files, or within index.html executes correctly.) I'm now on day 3 with this issue, and no end in sight.

Oddly enough, if we use the 'Request Desktop Site' feature within the browser, the site loads perfectly.

Thanks,

Cameron

Comment: Is this Angular or AngularJs?

Comment: Angular 7.2.10 - I mentioned this in the post but I will update the title with this info.

Comment: Sorry, the only real reason I asked is because you said it was the entry point of your application that doesn't load (but that part of your application is in fact AngularJS (1.3.15)). So I'm not sure if beyond that landing page is another Angular application that is 7.*

Comment: Ah, no the entry point should immediately bootstrap and load the angular application. I can see the <app-component> element, but it does not get populated with the application.